# why the associated goal is not executed when i run maven phase

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

Below is my maven plugin maven-dependency-plugin and the goal which is associated with phase package
i think if i run command mvn package, the goal (dependecy:copy-dependencies) should be executed, because this goal is associated with phase package, but it does not run. Could anyone give me some hints?

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

#

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>abc</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>abc</name>
<url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- mvn clean compile assembly:single -->
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>de.dbschenker.rail.sresb.messages.util.KafkaStreamsApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: First question: Why do you need such configuration?

Comment: i need copy all dependency jars into a separate directory

Comment: This is what I have understood based on the given configuration. But I want to know why do you want to do that? What kind of problem are you trying to solve? Can you give the project or at least the full pom file?

Comment: I second @khmarbaise question. Please elaborate.

Comment: the reason that i use maven-dependency-plugin , because i need to copy all dependency jars into separate folder as lib directory,  and the entire pom file i already provided here.

Comment: But _why_ do you want to copy all dependencies in a lib directory?

Comment: because i want to separate artifact jar and its dependency libs

Comment: Based on your enhancements I would suggest to use the maven-assembly-plugin and create a zip/tar.gz file which contains all the dependencies etc. nevertheless you have not answered the question why you want to do that? Would you like to create an executable jar? Or do you need that for a deployment on a particular platform ? Which looks like a Kafka...? If you already have a jar-with-dependencies the question is why do you want to copy the jars into a separate location?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply cause you have located the maven-dependency-plugin within a pluginManagement area which will not really execute the plugins.

It should look like this:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <!-- configure the plugin here -->
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

The pluginManagement area is intended to define the version and the configuration but not the execution itself.

Apart from that I don't see that you need this configuration cause you already using the maven-assembly-plugin.

Comment: maven-assembly-plugin package all dependency libs with artifact as one jar. but dependeny plugin can copy all dependeny libs into separate folder.